# Proof by characteristic functions that $X+Y$ and $2X$ are identically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

The exercise states that X,Y iid and we know that X+Y has Cauchy distribution. And they require to prove that 2X has also Cauchy distribution. Let me put it straight, I dont think I understand it fully , let's forget about Cauchy distribution at all.

Isn't it true for all distributions? If two random variables are iid, their characteristic functions are equal and

$$Ee^{itX}=Ee^{itY}$$
$$Ee^{it(X+Y)}=Ee^{itX}Ee^{itY}=Ee^{itX}Ee^{itX}=Ee^{it2X}$$ hence $2X$ has distribution as $X+Y$ almost surely?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are iid and (unless $X$ is almost everywhere constant) then $X+Y$ does **not** have the same distribution as $2X$.

Comment: Can you develop your thought? This would mean that this is a false statement, because X+Y would be constant almost everywhere

Comment: Why is $E(e^{itX})^2=E(e^{it2X})$?

Comment: Ok thanks, @LordSharktheUnknown, it is so beacuse cauchy characteristic function is $e^{-|x|}$ for all x

Comment: This is rather fascinating: you accepted, rather instantly, an answer which does not address your question at all. What is going on?

Comment: I wanted to close the question, because I already know my error and corrected it, because of the comment.

Comment: And, to "close the question", you accept an answer? Sorry but this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic function of $X$ is $\phi(t):=\exp (ix_0t-\gamma|t|)$. The desired result is $\phi^2(t)=\phi(2t)$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Lord Shark the Unknown, the error in your general proof is $(E e^{itX})^2 = E e^{it2X}$, which does not hold in general.

However, as you noted, in the case of $X$ being Cauchy with scale $\gamma$, the above becomes $$(e^{-\gamma|t|})^2 = e^{-\gamma |2t|}.$$